# Pixi.js - Re-positioning element after window resize

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'm quite a noob with Pixi.js so here comes the noob question.

I'm trying to display a square in the middle of the screen. When I resize the window, the square should stay in the middle.

When drawing the square I'm using

```
const square = new PIXI.Graphics();
square.beginFill(0xff0000, 1);
square.drawRect(app.renderer.width /2, app.renderer.height / 2, 50, 50);
square.endFill();
app.stage.addChild(square);
```

Then, I understand that the `x` and `y` properties of `square` are relative to the initial drawing position. So `square.x = 0` will keep the square in the middle.

But then, how do I reset the center of the window (and so the position of the square) when I resize it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be your solution. This is diametric resize response.

I use something like :

```
  getWidthByPer : function (per) {
     return window.innerWidth / 100 * per
  }
```

```js
console.log = function(){};

var app = new PIXI.Application({
 autoResize: true,
 resolution:  1.77 
});
document.querySelector("#MYAPP").appendChild(app.view);
 
const rect = new PIXI.Graphics()
  .beginFill(0x55faaf)
  .drawRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);
  
app.stage.addChild(rect);

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);

function resize() {

  const parent = app.view.parentNode;
  
  app.renderer.resize(parent.clientWidth, parent.clientHeight);
  
  rect.position.set(
    app.screen.width / 2 ,
    app.screen.height / 2
  );
}

window.onload = function(){
  resize();
};
```

```css
canvas {
  display:block;
}

#MYAPP {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top:0%;
  left:0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://pixijs.download/v4.7.0/pixi.min.js"></script>
<div id="MYAPP"></div>
```

Comment: Oh so you don't directly draw your Rect at the expected position [window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/2], you draw it relatively to [0,0] , and only then you position it. Got it, thanks!